# can't get the click position of a div element

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom-events, z-index

I want to create a minimap. So I have an accurate representation of div elements inside my minimap. I want the user to use the minimap to navigate around the site.

I get the correct position when I click inside my minimap (the gray box), but when I click on a "ghostly" or the green box, I get incorrect dimensions, which leads to an incorrect position setting.

here is a showcase:

```js
function getClickPosition(e) {
  // I need the click position of the gray box 
  // but when I click on the green or red box I get their values
  console.log(e.layerX)
}
```

```css
.minimap {
  height: 100px;
  width: 140px;
  background-color: #999;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 100;
}
.viewport-layer {
 height: 20px;
 width: 35px;
 left: 20px;
 top: 15px;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 position: absolute;
 border: 2px solid green;
 z-index: 101;
 max-width: 100px;
}
.ghosty-box {
  position: absolute;
  top: 60px;
  left: 90px;
  height: 30px;
  width: 40px;
  background-color: red;
  z-index: 0; // should be in the background
}
```

```html
<div class="minimap" onclick="getClickPosition(event)">
 <!-- user screen: green border -->
 <div class="viewport-layer">
 </div>
 <!-- dynamic size of the minimap -->
 <div class="relativeLayer">
  <!-- representation of the visible elements -->
  <div class="ghosty-box"></div>
 </div>
</div>
```

my console of `e` says something like:

```
click { target: div.ghosty-box, ... layerX: 10, layerY: 11 }
```

or

```
click { target: div.viewportLayer, ... layerX: 33, layerY: 16 }
```

I was expecting that a `z-index` would help.

Do you have any suggestions to get the click position of the `.minimap` or `.relativeLayer` with elements behind it?

So the `target` is **always** the gray box?

Comment: Something I have run into in the past is because of the nested nature of elements, even if what you're wanting to get the click for is the div, you may actually be clicking on a P tag or an A tag. The best way to go about it is using a button that's styled to not look like a button, or just use a regular button. This is good for the user experience as it shows them where to click, and it makes your code easier because you just listen for the button press.

Comment: so, no matter what element is clicked on inside the minimap, you want to get the position of that element relative to the boundry of the minimap? Does e.target always have to be minimap?

Comment: @Kwright02 Numerous other ways to handle the target issue without needing to introduce unwanted buttons

Comment: @Kinglish, exactly I just want the relative position. Where the value comes from doesn't matter. I thought it works easier via a div which has the dimensions of the page.

Comment: @wittgenstein - see if my updated answer helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want relative values of clicked elements inside of `minimap`. This will give you the relative X and Y of the clicked item - as well as the relative mouseX and mouseY (along with the relative percentage position)

```js
function getClickPosition(e) {
  // I need the click position of the gray box 
  // but when I click on the green or red box I get their values
  if (e.target.classList.contains('minimap')) {
    console.log('clicked on minimap background');
    return;
  }
  let ref = e.target.closest('.minimap').getBoundingClientRect()
  let pos = e.target.getBoundingClientRect();
  let posY = pos.top - ref.top
  let posX = pos.left - ref.left
  let mouseY = e.clientY - ref.top
  let mouseYPerc = ((mouseY / ref.height) * 100).toFixed(2);
  let mouseX = e.clientX - ref.top
  let mouseXPerc = ((mouseX / ref.width) * 100).toFixed(2)
  console.log('my relative position X:' + posX + ' Y:' + posY);
  console.log("relative mouseX:" + mouseX + " (" + mouseXPerc + "%) horiz");
  console.log("relative mouseY:" + mouseY + " (" + mouseYPerc + "%) vert");
}
```

```css
.minimap {
  height: 100px;
  width: 140px;
  background-color: #999;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 100;
  margin: 50px;
  opacity: .2;
}

.viewport-layer {
  height: 20px;
  width: 35px;
  left: 20px;
  top: 15px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  border: 2px solid green;
  z-index: 101;
  max-width: 100px;
}

.ghosty-box {
  position: absolute;
  top: 60px;
  left: 90px;
  height: 30px;
  width: 40px;
  background-color: red;
  z-index: 0; // should be in the background
}
```

```html
<div class="minimap" onclick="getClickPosition(event)">
  <!-- user screen: green border -->
  <div class="viewport-layer">
  </div>
  <!-- dynamic size of the minimap -->
  <div class="relativeLayer">
    <!-- representation of the visible elements -->
    <div class="ghosty-box"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: that is exactly what I wanted to achieve. thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not absolutely sure what readings you want out of the various layers, but a couple of comments:

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/UIEvent/layerX):

> This feature is non-standard and is not on a standards track. Do not use it on production sites facing the Web: it will not work for every user. There may also be large incompatibilities between implementations and the behavior may change in the future.

If you want the position relative to the gray box, as in your example, you may want to look at event.pageX or event.clientX. As in this snippet:

```js
function getClickPosition(e) {
  // I need the click position of the gray box 
  // but when I click on the green or red box I get their values
  console.log('pageX = ' + e.pageX);
  console.log('clientX = ' + e.clientX);
}
```

```css
.minimap {
  height: 100px;
  width: 140px;
  background-color: #999;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 100;
}
.viewport-layer {
 height: 20px;
 width: 35px;
 left: 20px;
 top: 15px;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 position: absolute;
 border: 2px solid green;
 z-index: 101;
 max-width: 100px;
}
.ghosty-box {
  position: absolute;
  top: 60px;
  left: 90px;
  height: 30px;
  width: 40px;
  background-color: red;
  z-index: 0; // should be in the background
}
```

```html
<div class="minimap" onclick="getClickPosition(event)">
 <!-- user screen: green border -->
 <div class="viewport-layer">
 </div>
 <!-- dynamic size of the minimap -->
 <div class="relativeLayer">
  <!-- representation of the visible elements -->
  <div class="ghosty-box"></div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Alternatively, when you process the click event you may want to check which actual element has been clicked when you have nested elements and/or you may or may not want to stop propagation. It's worth looking at an event object `console.log(e)` for example to see what the target is and the other settings you are given to get the right ones.

Comment: This looks very good. I will get back to you later. Thanks for now.

Answer (score 1):

if you don't really need to click the elements inside a good solution could be placing an absolute postioned empty layer covering the whole minimap just to capture the clicks. I added it to your snippet with the class `.position-layer`

```js
function getClickPosition(e) {
  // I need the click position of the gray box 
  // but when I click on the green or red box I get their values
  console.log(e.layerX);
  console.log(e.layerY);
}
```

```css
.minimap {
  height: 100px;
  width: 140px;
  background-color: #999;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 100;
}
.viewport-layer {
 height: 20px;
 width: 35px;
 left: 20px;
 top: 15px;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 position: absolute;
 border: 2px solid green;
 z-index: 101;
 max-width: 100px;
}
.ghosty-box {
  position: absolute;
  top: 60px;
  left: 90px;
  height: 30px;
  width: 40px;
  background-color: red;
  z-index: 0; // should be in the background
}

.position-layer {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index:1000;
}
```

```html
<div class="minimap">
 <!-- user screen: green border -->
 <div class="viewport-layer">
 </div>
 <!-- dynamic size of the minimap -->
 <div class="relativeLayer">
  <!-- representation of the visible elements -->
  <div class="ghosty-box"></div>
 </div>
 <div class="position-layer" onclick="getClickPosition(event)"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: nice. I wanted to do that too, but couldn't figure it out. got you an upvote.

Answer (score 0):

MDN says (I'm paraphrasing) that `layerX` is position of the mouse cursor relative to the clicked element or one of it's parents that is absolutely positioned element

Your ghosty-box is `position: absolute`, which means that is it's clicked, the `layerX` is relative to it.
If you could position it relatively or using margins, that would solve the issue.

Other option is using pageX or screenX and computing the offset yourself, or positioning an overlay element over the minimap and catching the click on that.

Comment: even if I set the elements `position: relative` they are still locked as target. I think your suggestion with pageX or screenX will lead to the goal.